# How to rename C++ files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C++ and programming. In an assignment for school, the teacher wants us to give the file a specific name, but when I open a new file it will be named "ConsoleApplication" or whatever and I don't know how to change it.

When I go to "save," there is no "save as" option. There is a "save output as" option, but I don't want to save just the output, I want the whole project.

Thank you.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Maybe use the file explorer of your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Either use your operating system's file explorer (on windows press windows button + e), as noted by drescherjm, or right click the file you want to change the name of inside of visual studio (there should be a box called solution explorer), and click "rename".